After override paintevent, QMovie's transparent background bug
void fonttiplineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QLineEdit::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);
    qDebug() << "event->rect().left():" << event->rect().left()
             << " event->rect().right():" << event->rect().right()
             << " event->rect().top():" << event->rect().top()
             << " event->rect().bottom():" << event->rect().bottom()
             << " event->rect().x():" << event->rect().x()
             << " event->rect().y():" << event->rect().y();

    QRectF textRect = event->rect().adjusted(11, 0, 0, 0);;
    QString text = m_text;

    QFont font("Microsoft YaHei"); // 设置字体
    font.setPixelSize(16);
    QPen pen(QColor("#3F3E3E")); // 设置画笔颜色

    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.setPen(pen);

    painter.drawText(textRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, text);
}

I override a paintevent of Qlinedit, so that some texts can be displayed on the left side

Then I created a QLabel, used setMovie to place a gif, and set the background transparent, placing it on top of lineedit
void bindinfoWindow::setstyle()
{
    phonelineEdit->setmtext(zh("手机号"));
    dingtalklineEdit->setmtext(zh("钉钉"));

    m_gifWaitWidget->setFixedSize(ui->mycentralwidget->size());
    m_gifWaitWidget->raise();
    m_gifWaitWidget->hide();
    m_movie = new QMovie(":/VPNClientRes/1920/gif/wait1.gif", QByteArray(), this);
    m_gifWaitLabel->setMovie(m_movie);
}

Something strange happened, the text in the override paintEvent was incorrectly displayed in the GIF
It is found through debug that GIF calls Paintevent

This is normal Paintevent
event->rect().left(): 0  event->rect().right(): 302  event->rect().top(): 0  event->rect().bottom(): 35  event->rect().x(): 0  event->rect().y(): 0
event->rect().left(): 0  event->rect().right(): 302  event->rect().top(): 0  event->rect().bottom(): 35  event->rect().x(): 0  event->rect().y(): 0

This is the gif call
event->rect().left(): 178  event->rect().right(): 209  event->rect().top(): 32  event->rect().bottom(): 35  event->rect().x(): 178  event->rect().y(): 32
event->rect().left(): 178  event->rect().right(): 209  event->rect().top(): 0  event->rect().bottom(): 17  event->rect().x(): 178  event->rect().y(): 0

My temporary workaround is to add a line to block the gif call
void fonttiplineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QLineEdit::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);

    if(event->rect().left() != 0) return; //block gifcall

    QRectF textRect = event->rect().adjusted(11, 0, 0, 0);;
    QString text = m_text;

    QFont font("Microsoft YaHei"); // 设置字体
    font.setPixelSize(16);
    QPen pen(QColor("#3F3E3E")); // 设置画笔颜色

    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.setPen(pen);

    painter.drawText(textRect, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter, text);
}

But I don't know the fundamental reason. The QT version I am using is 5.15.2

Don't post code or text as images, among other things it's practically uinvisible\unreadable. About the problem - it rather causes update be called, as the client area is being invalidated. paintEvent is the actual method which does re-draw.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Using the event rect as absolute reference for drawing is completely wrong and inappropriate: all widgets could be updated with any arbitrary event rect, just for optimization reasons. You should at least assume that the text area is based on the widget rect(), but consider that using arbitrary margins (that 11 offset) is completely unreliable, and you should use QStyle functions instead.
